# loop through a subfolder in bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I am super fresh in the bash language and I am missing several key concepts.
Please excuse my ignorance.

My structure is

```
folder A
   |--- folderB1q/output/output.csv
   |--- folderB2q/output/output.csv
   |--- ...
   |--- folderB100q/output/output.csv
```

I want to read in bash from folder A each output.csv file and apply a function on it. I have tested my function and it works when I go to the directory of the file.
I have thousands of directories though...

```
for each in *q/output/ 
do
my function .......
done
```

Thank you for your time and sorry for my bad coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> each output.csv

Then loop over `output.csv` files.

```
for each in */output/output.csv
do
    my function "$each"
done
```

> I have thousands of directories though...

With many directories, using a shell loop might be memory expensive, because shell. Use a `find`.

```
find . -type f -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -path '.*/output/output.csv' |
xargs -d'\n' -n1 my_command
```